# Hide or disable drop down list menu buttons. jQuery of JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created 3 options list which are attached at the end of a table row. I want to hide or disable Edit and Copy options if certain conditions are not met when page loads. How can i do this using either jQuery of JavaScript.

```
<div class="btn-group ewButtonGroup open">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-small" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Options <b class="caret"></b></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu ewMenu">
        <li><a class="ewRowLink ewView" data-caption="View" href="teamsview.php?showdetail=&amp;TeamID=1">View</a></li>
        <li><a class="ewRowLink ewEdit" data-caption="Edit" href="teamsedit.php?TeamID=1">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a class="ewRowLink ewCopy" data-caption="Copy" href="teamsadd.php?TeamID=1">Copy</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried the following code which deosnt work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     var Week_Check = $('#ewRowLink ewView span').text();
     if ( Week_Check > 10) {
         $('.ewRowLink ewView').hide();
     } 
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bad jQuery selector. If you want to hide an element having both of those classes you want to go this way:

```
$('.ewRowLink.ewView').hide();
```

By using `$('.ewRowLink ewView').hide();` you basically state: hide all ewView (?) elements that are inside other elements having ewRowLink class.

Comment: Thanks, it now working but hides in all rows. Is there a way to hide that specific row. I have many rows in the table. Thanks

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what you mean. Try to clarify what's the actual problem. I only noticed that your selector wasn't working but now I see there's not enough info to fully understand what's wrong.

Comment: I have many rows like this. I will check certain data in each row and if it meets a condition, the hide is activated.

Comment: Well you gonna have to somehow identify what needs to be hidden. Assigning IDs to the rows itself might help. If you have similar constructions in every row you might achieve this using a selector $('#yourRowId .ewRowLink.ewView').hide();

Comment: Final; $('#r1_teams .ewEdit, #r1_teams .ewCopy').hide();

Comment: This will hide any nodes having ewEdit OR ewCopy class inside a node with id r1_teams

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.off()` to unbind the event:

```
$('.ewEdit, .ewCopy').off('click');
```

or if you want to hide:

```
$('.ewEdit, .ewCopy').hide();
```

---

Yet you need to mention on what condition you want to do this.

Comment: oh! yeah i got this now, actually it seems you have not bound any click event to it that's why `.off()` is not working.

Comment: Is there a way i can hide for that particular row. It hides in all rows. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes that is possible but you need to have some kind of identification or anything specific to that row on that basis we can hide the links.

Comment: Each row has an id. Examples id="r1_teams" id="r2_teams"  etc, they are dynamically created as data is entered.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     var Week_Check = $('#ewRowLink, #ewView').find('span').html();
     if ( Week_Check > 10) {
         $('.ewRowLink, .ewView').hide();
     } 
 });
 </script>
```